# With GKE Autopilot banning the cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict=false annotation, is there a way to ensure job pods do not get evicted?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

Our GKE Autopilot cluster was recently upgraded to version 1.21.6-gke.1503, which apparently causes the `cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict=false` annotation to be banned.

I totally get this for deployments, as Google doesn't want a deployment preventing scale-down, but for jobs I'd argue this annotation makes perfect sense in certain cases. We start complex jobs that start and monitor other jobs themselves, which makes it hard to make them restart-resistant given the sheer number of moving parts.

**Is there any way to make it as unlikely as possible for job pods to be restarted/moved around when using Autopilot?** Prior to switching to Autopilot, we used to make sure our jobs filled a single node by requesting all of its available resources; combined with a Guaranteed QoS class, this made sure the only way for a pod to be evicted was if the node somehow failed, which almost never happened. Now all we seem to have left is the Guaranteed QoS class, but that doesn't prevent pods from being evicted.

Comment: Please update your question with some examples and/or reproduction steps; maybe yaml files etc. The more details the better.

Comment: @Wojtek_B It's hard to provide examples for a case like this, as the jobs are pretty complex and the issue seems unpredictable. It does seem to happen more often when the cluster is running many (parent) jobs in parallel, so it could be related to resources becoming available when some pods terminate. 

So let's look at this from a theoretical standpoint: if we have jobs A and B on node 1 and job C on node 2, each job consuming 50% of the resources of a node. If job B terminates, is there any point where the scheduler will move job C to node 1 so it can terminate node 2 and save resources?

Comment: The above scenario is possible.  Have you looked into using PDBs?

Comment: @GariSingh Nope. I'm guessing creating a PDB with `maxUnavailable: 0` matching say a `prevent-eviction` label and setting that label on my job pods would work? But then a) how is this different from the `safe-to-evict` annotation and why not allow it in Autopilot the first place? and b) what guarantees do I have that this won't end up being banned in Autopilot as well?

Comment: @GariSingh After investigating PDBs it turns out they don't work with jobs, so unless I missed something that won't work.

Comment: Did you try adding [`nodeSelector` field](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#step-two-add-a-nodeselector-field-to-your-pod-configuration) ?

Comment: @Wojtek_B Unless I'm missing something, I don't see how having a node selector would help us avoid evictions, since AFAIK node selectors only tell the scheduler which nodes we want or don't want a pod to run on?

Comment: @PLPeeters - I think you can use PDBs with Jobs but you can only use `minAvailable`

Comment: @GariSingh `minAvailable` doesn't work for our use case. Our jobs are spawned on-demand with unique names, meaning this would require a different PDB for each job (otherwise the PDB would span across multiple jobs, rendering it useless). We really need a solution for this as right now running multiple jobs in parallel leads to mayhem due to pods being moved around. We'd really like to avoid having to abandon Autopilot because of this.

Comment: I'd hate to see you abandon Autopilot as well.  Working with others on the team to explore other options.

Comment: Is there a maximum amount of time the Job needs to run for? For example, if you could set a large enough `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` would that suffice?

Comment: @WilliamDenniss Depending on the job it can range anywhere from 10 minutes to multiple days. Apparently there's no max value in Kubernetes (would have to check for GKE), but then if I set `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` to the maximum possible value, it's basically the same as using the `safe-to-evict` annotation, so why not just allow that one in the first place? And since it would be virtually the same resource-hogging wise as the annotation, I'm concerned about a future ban/cap on that as well since it would lead to the same problem.

Comment: In addition, when people search for a solution to avoid pod eviction, the `safe-to-evict` annotation is the answer they'll find most often, so in that regard it also makes sense for Autopilot to support it IMO, since its aim seems to be making Kubernetes use as frictionless as possible.

Comment: @WilliamDenniss Unfortunately after some tests `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` is not a viable solution either as the autoscaler sets a 10-minute override when scaling down a node. I had a pod with a 7-day grace period and when it got terminated for node scale-down the grace period was set to 600 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [now supported](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/extended-duration-pods) in GKE Autopilot, from 1.27+.

`cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict=false` will prevent GKE-initiated disruption to the Pod for 7 days (including auto-scaling related, and update related disruption).

Answer (score 1):

At this point the only thing left is to ask to bring back this feature on [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) - raise a new feature reqest and hope for the best.

Link to this thread also as it contains quite a lot of troubleshooting and may be useful.

Comment: [Issue created](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227162588) as a bug, since this worked before and no longer does.